# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::bigIncrements(), 0 passed

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-8

I want to make a new migration for my project, and this migration is called `create_active_code.php` and goes like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('active_code', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('code');
        $table->unique(['user_id', 'code']);
        $table->timestamps('expired_at');
    });
}
```

But as soon as I run this migration, I get this error:

> **ArgumentCountError**
> Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::bigIncrements(), 0 passed in F:\xampp\htdocs\frameworks\rooket2\database\migrations\2020_11_30_055654_create_active_code.php on line 17 and exactly 1 expected

So how to solve this ?

Comment: Change `bigIncrements()` to `id()`

Comment: Now it says: `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'expired_at) null, `updated_at` timestamp(expired_at) null) default character set' at line 1 (SQL: create table `active_code` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` bigint unsigned not null, `code` int not null, `created_at` timestamp(expired_at) null, `updated_at` timestamp(expired_at) null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')`

Comment: This may be due to MySQL version

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'expired_at)

```php
$table->timestamps();
```

is used by laravel to create `created_at` & `updated_at` fields. if you want to create expire_at you need to use

```php
$table->timestamp('expire_at');
```

you have spelling mistake.

Comment: Now it says: `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") `

Comment: what version of laravel you are using ?

Comment: If you are using laravel8 convert your code  from `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->references('id')->on('user')->onDelete('cascade');`


Into

`$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');`

Answer (score 1):

your not passing the column name for bigIncrements
try this

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```